# Roll MySql queries into next column using php.

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am creating a monitor display that needs to be able to display 16 numbers at a time. 8 in one table and 8 in the next table. Right now I have to tables that just keep going down the rows based on the number of entries I have in my MySql data base. What I need is for 2 columns in each table (4 numbers in each column) and limit them to the most recent 8 numbers for each given category.

Here is what I have so far:
Some help would be greatly appreciated, I'm pretty stuck on this, thank you.

```
    $select_query = "SELECT buyback.buyback_callNumber
      FROM buyback WHERE buyback.buyback_status = 'In-Progress' ";
    $select_query2 = "SELECT buyback.buyback_callNumber 
      FROM buyback WHERE buyback.buyback_status = 'Ready for Pickup'";

$result = mysql_query($select_query);



echo "
<align='center'>
<div class='span9' >
<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
<tr>
<td><strong><h3>In-Progress</h3></strong></td>
</tr>"; 
 while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";

echo "
<td><strong><h3>".$record['buyback_callNumber'] ."</h3></strong></td></tr>";

}
echo "</table></div>";

echo "
<div class='span9'>
<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
<tr>
<td><strong><h3>Ready</h3></strong></td>
</tr>";

$result2 = mysql_query($select_query2);
while($record2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
echo "<tr>";

echo"
<td><strong><h3>".$record2['buyback_callNumber'] ."</h3></strong></td></tr>";

}
echo "</table></div></align>";



echo "</form>  ";
```

Comment: Without seeing proper DLL's I'm not sure how we're supposed to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for limiting results to 8 per table, just add 'LIMIT 8' to each query (you may want to ORDER these queries as well by date or some other field you may have set up)

```
$select_query = "SELECT buyback.buyback_callNumber
  FROM buyback WHERE buyback.buyback_status = 'In-Progress' LIMIT 8";
$select_query2 = "SELECT buyback.buyback_callNumber 
  FROM buyback WHERE buyback.buyback_status = 'Ready for Pickup' LIMIT 8";
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful do you know how I would get them to go in side by side 4 in each column rather than just going straight down?

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you want to use `table` when this can be achieved with `div's` only.
To align the columns side by side place `float:left` in the divs you want to show side by side.

```
<div style="float:left> 1st 4 values </div>
<div style="float:left> 2nd 4 values </div>
```

just a generic suggestion, avoid using tables for html layout as they are outdated and html has attributes like `display: table-row`, `display: table-cell;` to suit the purpose

Comment: this is in addition to what Chris has answered! (: